# Trying to find old story of alien who looks like a dog, boy and dog go to the moon

Tags: story-identification, telepathy, moon

I am looking for the title and/or author of a book or short story from either the 50's or 60's that I read when I was a teenager. In the book, a boy finds a dog (that may have crash-landed on earth). The dog is alien and telepathic. Somehow they go to the moon. The alien dog lets the boy know about something on the moon that is not a bomb. The boy figures this out by the phrase from the bible: "there is no balm in gilead".

Comment: The Gilead Bomb by David Sinclair is a good suggestion but I don't think it is the book I am searching for. In the story that I remember, the boy is an ordinary boy and did not have his own rocket, that I remember. He definitely starts out on earth and finds the telepathic dog there. Together they go to the moon, but I don't remember in whose rocket. One part that I do remember is the boy out on the surface of the moon. He was alone, and the sunny areas were dangerously hot. A definite quote is the one above: "there is no balm in gilead". The dog's name might be "Sirius".

Comment: You may be conflating memories.  The bible quote is the key plot point in The Gilead Bomb.  Also, the dog is named Sirius.

Comment: Other details that I remember from the 1960s: The rocket had an experimental ion drive - it launched on a pillar of blue light.  Sirius was the boy's dog from early childhood and is revealed to be a sentient alien telepath only at the end of the book. The Big Bad Alien at the end of the book is also a telepath.

Comment: More:  Ace, the boy, is an orphan.  Parents killed on ground by meteor storm when Ace was very young.  Revealed later that meteor storm was actually reentry debris from Sirius' busted up starship.  Dog indirectly responsible for parents death and so chooses to hide in plain site as the boy's guardian.

Comment: Possibly more, but less clearly remembered:  The Big Bad is bipedal, telepathic, has one eye with wavy worm tendril things around it.  Maybe called Rim, but I don't know if that is a name or a species designation.  Sirius kills it in a telepathic battle.  That's probably all I will be able to recall.  I was maybe six the last time I read it.

Answer (score 5):

*[The Gilead Bomb](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Gilead_Bomb.html?id=htGAPQAACAAJ)*, David Sinclair, 1963, part of the *Ace Astro and the Star Rovers* series.  Had a copy when I was a kid.

> Ace Astro lands his rocket on the United States Moon Installation to discover something is very wrong. The base is deserted and the planet-to-planet radio is destroyed. Alone with his dog and a Russian cosmonaut, they must discover what is going on.

[image: Front cover of The Gilead Bomb] as per [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13487088-the-gilead-bomb).

[This review](https://books.google.ch/books?id=wbMXAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Ace%20Astro%20and%20the%20star%20rovers%22&dq=%22Ace%20Astro%20and%20the%20star%20rovers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWh4aIqKn3AhVGwKQKHeAuDwAQ6AF6BAgHEAI) mentions a mind control machine as part of the problem they're trying to solve.

Comment: Can you state (maybe quote from Goodreads) why this is a good match?

Comment: Wow... this one seems a bit obscure. @Valorum?

Comment: [Google Books says](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Gilead_Bomb.html?id=htGAPQAACAAJ): *Ace Astro lands his rocket on the United States Moon Installation to discover something is very wrong. The base is deserted and the planet-to-planet radio is destroyed. Alone with his dog and a Russian cosmonaut, they must discover what is going on.* Does that ring any bells?

Comment: I don't know about the OP, but I've been trying to recall this book for years and all I could remember was the moon, a boy, a building in a crater and an odd name. In this case, the cover art is worth a 1K words

Comment: Everything I remember is in my comments above.  I know this is the book.

Answer (score 0):

Dogsbody by DIANA WYNNE JONES sounds a little like it

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you add some details to provide evidence this is the correct match.